# Solr-5.4.0 not accepting json input

Tags: json, solr

I am trying to use solr-5.4.0. I need to do implement, search functionality using solr for json files.I have started solr in command prompt.Now using cygwin to update json.But showing the following html error.I didn't got an clear idea to work in solr.Please anyone help to solve this.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '

[
 {
  "id"        : "TestDoc1",
  "title"     : {"set":"test1"},
  "revision"  : {"inc":3},
  "publisher" : {"add":"TestPublisher"}
  "_version_" : {12345}
 }
]'


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't include a core name. The URL is usually something like `http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/update` - you're missing the core name part.

Comment: @user57 Can you access the Admin interface at all?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,I am new to solr.I have just installed and tried to run it.I also tried running in http://localhost:8983/solr/  User interface,there also had the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like your Solr installation isn't running at all